# MySQL Problem fetching the info row

Tags: craft3

since yesterday i have been trying to setup Craft CMS for the first time, 
but the installation fails and tells me to check the logs.

The database account has all rights.

(This is only a part of the log, but this should do)

```
2020-05-05 07:25:50 [-][-][-][info][yii\db\Connection::open] Opening DB connection: mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=craftycoffee
2020-05-05 07:25:50 [-][-][-][profile begin][yii\db\Connection::open] Opening DB connection: mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=craftycoffee
2020-05-05 07:25:50 [-][-][-][profile end][yii\db\Connection::open] Opening DB connection: mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=craftycoffee
2020-05-05 07:25:53 [-][-][-][info][yii\db\Command::query] SELECT *
FROM `info`
WHERE `id`=1
LIMIT 1
2020-05-05 07:25:53 [-][-][-][profile begin][yii\db\Command::query] SELECT *
FROM `info`
WHERE `id`=1
LIMIT 1
2020-05-05 07:25:53 [-][-][-][profile end][yii\db\Command::query] SELECT *
FROM `info`
WHERE `id`=1
LIMIT 1
2020-05-05 07:25:53 [-][-][-][error][craft\base\ApplicationTrait::getIsInstalled] There was a problem fetching the info row: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'craftycoffee.info' doesn't exist
The SQL being executed was: SELECT *
FROM `info`
WHERE `id`=1
LIMIT 1
2020-05-05 07:25:53 [-][-][-][error][yii\db\Exception] PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'craftycoffee.info' doesn't exist in E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php:1293
Stack trace:
#0 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(1293): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(1159): yii\db\Command->internalExecute('SELECT *\nFROM `...')
#2 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(415): yii\db\Command->queryInternal('fetch', NULL)
#3 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Query.php(274): yii\db\Command->queryOne()
#4 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\db\Query.php(168): yii\db\Query->one(NULL)
#5 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\ApplicationTrait.php(620): craft\db\Query->one()
#6 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\ApplicationTrait.php(286): craft\web\Application->getInfo(true)
#7 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\services\Sites.php(1138): craft\web\Application->getIsInstalled()
#8 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\services\Sites.php(448): craft\services\Sites->_loadAllSites()
#9 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(180): craft\services\Sites->setCurrentSite(NULL)
#10 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(558): yii\base\Component->__set('currentSite', NULL)
#11 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(craft\services\Sites), Array)
#12 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#13 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(400): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#14 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\services\\...', Array, Array)
#15 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\services\\...', Array, Array)
#16 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#17 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('sites', true)
#18 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(341): yii\base\Module->get('sites', true)
#19 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\ApplicationTrait.php(1238): craft\web\Application->get('sites')
#20 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Request.php(185): craft\web\Application->getSites()
#21 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Request->init()
#22 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#23 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(400): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#24 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#25 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#26 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\config\app.web.php(13): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#27 [internal function]: {closure}()
#28 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(524): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#29 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->invoke(Object(Closure), Array)
#30 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Object(Closure))
#31 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('request', true)
#32 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(341): yii\base\Module->get('request', true)
#33 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(160): craft\web\Application->get('request')
#34 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\ApplicationTrait.php(1380): yii\web\Application->getRequest()
#35 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(100): craft\web\Application->_preInit()
#36 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Application->init()
#37 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#38 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(91): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#39 [internal function]: craft\web\Application->__construct(Array)
#40 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(400): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#41 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#42 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#43 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\bootstrap\bootstrap.php(245): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#44 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\bootstrap\web.php(51): require('E:\\WAMP\\www\\cra...')
#45 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\web\index.php(20): require('E:\\WAMP\\www\\cra...')
#46 {main}

Next yii\db\Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'craftycoffee.info' doesn't exist
The SQL being executed was: SELECT *
FROM `info`
WHERE `id`=1
LIMIT 1 in E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:674
Stack trace:
#0 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(1298): yii\db\Schema->convertException(Object(PDOException), 'SELECT *\nFROM `...')
#1 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(1159): yii\db\Command->internalExecute('SELECT *\nFROM `...')
#2 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(415): yii\db\Command->queryInternal('fetch', NULL)
#3 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Query.php(274): yii\db\Command->queryOne()
#4 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\db\Query.php(168): yii\db\Query->one(NULL)
#5 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\ApplicationTrait.php(620): craft\db\Query->one()
#6 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\ApplicationTrait.php(286): craft\web\Application->getInfo(true)
#7 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\services\Sites.php(1138): craft\web\Application->getIsInstalled()
#8 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\services\Sites.php(448): craft\services\Sites->_loadAllSites()
#9 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(180): craft\services\Sites->setCurrentSite(NULL)
#10 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(558): yii\base\Component->__set('currentSite', NULL)
#11 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(craft\services\Sites), Array)
#12 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#13 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(400): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#14 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\services\\...', Array, Array)
#15 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\services\\...', Array, Array)
#16 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#17 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('sites', true)
#18 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(341): yii\base\Module->get('sites', true)
#19 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\ApplicationTrait.php(1238): craft\web\Application->get('sites')
#20 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Request.php(185): craft\web\Application->getSites()
#21 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Request->init()
#22 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#23 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(400): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#24 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#25 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Reque...', Array, Array)
#26 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\config\app.web.php(13): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#27 [internal function]: {closure}()
#28 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(524): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#29 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(349): yii\di\Container->invoke(Object(Closure), Array)
#30 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(137): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Object(Closure))
#31 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(742): yii\di\ServiceLocator->get('request', true)
#32 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(341): yii\base\Module->get('request', true)
#33 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(160): craft\web\Application->get('request')
#34 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\base\ApplicationTrait.php(1380): yii\web\Application->getRequest()
#35 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(100): craft\web\Application->_preInit()
#36 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Application->init()
#37 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#38 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(91): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#39 [internal function]: craft\web\Application->__construct(Array)
#40 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(400): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#41 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#42 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#43 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\bootstrap\bootstrap.php(245): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#44 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\vendor\craftcms\cms\bootstrap\web.php(51): require('E:\\WAMP\\www\\cra...')
#45 E:\WAMP\www\craftycoffee\web\index.php(20): require('E:\\WAMP\\www\\cra...')
#46 {main}
Additional Information:
Array
(
    [0] => 42S02
    [1] => 1146
    [2] => Table 'craftycoffee.info' doesn't exist
)
```

Edit:
I also tried to install it with composer, but it gives me the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Hti.jpg

Comment: Do you have a `craftycoffee` database and does it have an `info` table?

Comment: @Oli Yes, it does. However, the info table is empty.

Comment: Strange... The error suggest the table doesn't even exist. Could you try to give remote access to your user, see here - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186309 then try the install again.

Comment: I have put the following in my db, but without success: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'172.0.0.1';

Comment: It looks like you are using `localhost` in your connection though and not `172.0.0.1`

Comment: So I tried making a new virtual host named "craftycoffee.test" instead of using localhost, and then tried giving my new database the priviliges with "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'user'@'craftycoffee.test';" but still no success.

Comment: Are you re-installing each time?

Comment: Yes, but before i reinstall, i have to drop my database because it will not let me install it again otherwise

Comment: I just noticed that all my tables are being made, but none of them get filled with data, i thought only info was empty... Maybe this clarifies something?

Comment: Could you have a look here (related to the error you get with composer but could help..) https://stackoverflow.com/a/31276668

Comment: @Oli Did you get my support mail back?